# Email is not sending in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send email from my Laravel Application. But email is not sending. I am using Laravel 8. My code is like below.
`.env` file code is like below.

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

`SendWelcomeMailToNewUser.php` file is like below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendWelcomeMailToNewUser
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $userId;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

`SendMailFired.php` file is like below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\SendWelcomeMailToNewUser;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Mail\RegistrationMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendMailFired
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Events\SendWelcomeMailToNewUser  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(SendWelcomeMailToNewUser $event)
    {
        //Log::info('info to log');  // This log is working fine.

        $details = [
            'title' => 'Mail from Promise 2 Deliver',
            'body'  => 'This is your first mail using smtp',
        ];

        Mail::to('abueabu@gmail.com')->send( new RegistrationMail($details) );
    }
}
```

`config/mail.php`

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Mailer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
    | messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
    | and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array", "failover"
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t'),
            // 'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'),
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],

        'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

`RegistrationMail.php` file is like below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class RegistrationMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $details;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('email.registration_email');
    }
}
```

`registration_email.blade.php` is like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Titile</h1>
    <p>body</p>
    <p>Thank you</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to send email when user register through API.

My  `register` function is like below.

```
 public function apiregister(StoreUserRequest $request)
    {
        if( $request->is('api/*')){
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'phone' => $request->phone,
                'address' => $request->address,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            ]);
    
            
            if ( $user ) {
                event(new SendWelcomeMailToNewUser($request->email));


                $response = ['user' => $user, "message" => "Registration successful"];
                return response( $response, 200 );
            } else {
                $response = ["message" => 'Registration failed.'];
                return response( $response, 422 );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how did you setup your queues?

Answer (score 2):

```
You Need To register Your Event and Listner in 
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider.

Follow link = https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events


Example as as follow:


    protected $listen = [
        \App\Events\OrderShipped::class => [    
           \App\Listeners\SendShipmentNotification::class,
        ],
    ];
```